# Telegram Bot: get chat Id group

Tags: c#, .net, telegram, telegram-bot

I've created a Telegram Bot using C# and I want to see who is using my bot when sending message.
I can get when people send a message to my bot in private chat but in the Groups, I can't get Username who is using Bot and it's return the GroupName.

The method I use is

```
var me = Bot.GetChatAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id).Result;
```

Comment: BTW, use of `var` is only necessary when dealing with anonymous types... try to use explicit type instead of `var`. (IDE0008)

Comment: My problem is  its return name of telegram group

Comment: After any await method using, await it and don't put `.Result` The code will get error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see who send message in `e.Message.From`, this property returns who send it as `User`.

And you should await methods that is awaitable.

---

And in your case `Bot.GetChatAsync`, this will return `Chat` from ChatId.

It means: Info about chat from Id.

And you pass `Chat` not `ChatId` to `Bot.GetChatAsync`

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types) this field `User` is optional for groups.

Comment: I had give admin permission to my Bot

Comment: @this_isName please read message section carefully , **from** not presented for groups